# How can I compare a date field with date.today and display the differance?

Tags: ruby, date, compare

I have a table of accounts, each with an expiration date. The expiration date is saved in a date field (day, month and year).

How can I compare this to the current date and display the number of days until the expiration date is reached?

Thanks for any help it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple `(Date.today - account.expiration_date).to_i` will give you the integer number - the difference in days :)

Comment: Thanks very much! However it displays the number of days with a '/1' after, any thoughts on what that could be?

Comment: I am not sure, I don't have ruby install on this machine so I can not check it for you. But you can also try '(Date.today - account.expiration_date).to_i' Maybe this will get rid of the '/1'?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your components into a target date and use some of the methods in DateHelper to display a human readable distance:

```
target_date = Date.new(model.year, model.month, model.day)

distance_of_time_in_words(target_date, Date.today)
=> "4 months"
```